# not able to fetch video from the URI that I have sent in new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE); in android 12/13

Tags: java, android

I want to capture video for 60 sec using Intent.
To do so, I have created a video file and sent it's URI in the Intent object.
The bellow code works fine in android 9 but fails for android 12/13.

Intent object and its parameters:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileUri("" + System.currentTimeMillis())); // set the video file


                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    videoCaptureResultLauncher.launch(intent);
                }
```

ActivityResultLauncher code:-

```
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> videoCaptureResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        try {
                            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                // There are no request codes
                                Intent data = result.getData();
                                videoCaptureResponse(data);//intent result response is sent here
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        }
                    }
                });

    private void videoCaptureResponse(Intent data) throws IOException {
        Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedVideoUri);
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] arr = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        int sizeOfInputStram = arr.length;

        stringEncoded = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(arr, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        
        MediaMetadataRetriever mMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mMMR.setDataSource(WitnessCRPCActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);
        Bitmap bmp = mMMR.getFrameAtTime();
        filecamera.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

I expect the to read the video URI having video data in it in android OS 12/13. I tried by giving read/write access to URI using flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);` but it did not work.

Comment: "but fails for android 12/13" -- what *exactly* does "fails" mean? For example, are you crashing? If so, [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html).

Comment: not able to get the video that I just recorded using the intent. The URI that i get using "data.getData();" is of a empty file. (len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 is false.

Comment: Tell the value of your file uri. You use a wrong uri we think. Post the code that generates the uri too.

Comment: `To do so, I have created a video file` You should not already create an empty file. You only need a File instance for your file. The File instance has the same path of the -now not- created file.

Comment: The same code works fine in Android 9 (Redmi 6). What could be wrong in Android 12 or Android 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same code works fine in Android 9 (Redmi 6)

No, it works fine on one device with one video recorder app, out of tens of thousands of devices and hundreds of video recorder apps. That app is being generous and is returning a `Uri` to you. [The app does not have to do that if you provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#action_video_capture), as you are doing.

Plus, these video recorder apps have bugs.

If you fail to get a usable `Uri` back, try looking in the location that you provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and see if the video is there. If it is, use it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. removing intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileUri("" + System.currentTimeMillis())); did the trick